Generate nested-variable with style-dictionary
I'm using Style Dictionary to generate a theme.js file from JSON tokens. However, the output is flat, and I want to preserve the nested structure of the tokens.
Here’s an example:
Input (tokens/colors.json):
{
  "colors": {
    "primary": {
      "light": { "$value": "#FFCC00" },
      "dark": { "$value": "#FF9900" }
    },
    "secondary": {
      "light": { "$value": "#00CCFF" },
      "dark": { "$value": "#0066FF" }
    }
  }
}

Desired Output (theme.js):
export const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: {
      light: "#FFCC00",
      dark: "#FF9900"
    },
    secondary: {
      light: "#00CCFF",
      dark: "#0066FF"
    }
  }
};

Currently, my output is flat, like this:
export const ColorsPrimaryLight = "#FFCC00";
export const ColorsPrimaryDark = "#FF9900";
export const ColorsSecondaryLight = "#00CCFF";
export const ColorsSecondaryDark = "#0066FF";


I registered a custom javascript/nested format but couldn't make it work as expected.
My current configuration simplifies the output, but it doesn't preserve the nesting.
const StyleDictionary = require('style-dictionary');

StyleDictionary.registerFormat({
  name: 'javascript/nested',
  formatter: ({ dictionary }) => {
    return `export const theme = ${JSON.stringify(dictionary.tokens, null, 2)};`;
  },
});
module.exports = {
  source: ['tokens/**/*.json'],
  platforms: {
    js: {
      transformGroup: 'js',
      buildPath: 'build/js/',
      files: [
        {
          destination: 'theme.js',
          format: 'javascript/nested',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

My package.json
{
  "name": "style",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}

I get an error
TypeError: StyleDictionary.extend is not a function
How can I configure Style Dictionary to generate a theme.js file with a nested structure like the one I want?

You can use the built-in javascript/object format.
(you can also change the name of the variable using the name option)
current version (v4) reference
previous version reference
